# How should I handle killing (or not) this character?

Tags: dnd-5e, gm-techniques, character-death, story, villain

So I've been playing with the same group for a long time and they aren't the smartest which has led to the loss of many PCs in this D&D game. Only one has survived this entire time. His name is Blognark and the entire party loves him (including me).

I however want to create an antagonist that the PC's hate, so, I have been tossing around the idea of killing off Blognark for the story telling.

Now I have no idea how Blognark's player is going to react to his super powerful character dying, and if I did kill him I'd want him to die majestically (he's quite selfless). He also is probably my favorite player because his backstory and style so I don't want to bum him out with the loss of Blognark.

I'd like to know ***if*** I should kill him and ***how*** I should go about it to make the best experience for the party.

Comment: It sounds like Blognark is a player's character, is that right?

Comment: While it may not necessarily have a huge impact on the answer, you should also tell which edition you're playing.

Comment: Blognark is a PC and we are playing 5e Blognark has been the guys character for a LONG time

Comment: Related: [How to kill a character without making their player too angry](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/22284/32395)

Comment: You describe Blognark as a "super powerful character". Why is he so strong? Do you punish Players when their characters die, for example by having them start at a lower level?

Comment: Welcome to RPG Stack Exchange, Evan! Check out our [tour] to see how we work here. This is a pretty excellent first question, and I'm happy to see it here. You've reached 20 reputation already, so you can join us in [chat] if you'd like.

Comment: I'm not  sure "should I kill a character"  can be answered  in any way other  than people's purely subjective opinions. How  to do it in a way that achieves your goals is the on topic part of this question I believe..

Comment: @mxyzplk I think rather than answering whether it should happen in this scenario, we *could* educate the querent on how to figure out for themselves whether it should happen. The primary answer to that below has been talk to them about it and see if they'll be OK with it.

Comment: I disagree,  "you should only kill a PC with player agreement" is opinion on how it should be done as much as any other answer.

Comment: Are you looking for a way to make the nasty guy appear very nasty? For a way to get rid of this overpowerful (even if awesome) PC? Are you just wondering if killing him can make a great moment of playing?

Comment: @doppelgreener  The querent (without IMO realizing this) has already answered their own question in paragraph three.  I suggest this stay closed, per mxy's point.

Comment: I agree this is somewhat opinion based... GMs imo shouldn't kill PCs, giving them enough rope to kill themselves is another matter. But it seems the end goal is not to kill them but merely a method to a further goal... making the BBG hated... that can be done in other ways just as easily without infringing on PC's free will. Perhaps rewording the question to that effect might help get this reopened?

Comment: Related: [How do I create a great fantasy villain that inspires the party to rally against them?](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/584/1204) / [How to make your players hate your villain, but not your game](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/55712/1204) / [How to make a great villain who your players hate more than anything else?](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/55597/1204) / [How can I create more compelling villains?](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/36516/1204)

Comment: @Slagmoth As a long time believer in "give 'em enough rope" amen, and perhaps this question needs more depth.  Also, it may be a dupe for one of the questions doppelgreener has linked to.

Answer (score 12):

## *Should* you kill Blognark? Only by mutual agreement with the player.

You should discuss this with the player before doing so. What you're describing is not a "naturally" occurring death due to emergent gameplay based on player agency, which is how the rest of the PC's died. You're describing a planned death that is central to the plot. If you do not get approval from the player, I suspect they will be very displeased.

The other PC's died as a result of the players' own agency in the story in some fashion or another, as you've described. You should afford Blognark's player the same sense by giving that player agency over whether you kill off his character. In addition, if it is planned with that player, you can ensure that the scene does indeed play out dramatically, so that you can all but ensure it will come off as the pivotal, motivating scene you want it to be. I think any other course of action will sour the experience for all your players, especially the one who plays Blognark.

## *How* can you kill Blognark for the best experience? As the consequence of a selfless, heroic, voluntary act.

The most rewarding and motivational solution I've experienced to the goal you are trying to achieve is to allow Blognark to commit a singularly selfless, heroic act (presuming his alignment is somewhere on the neutral or good spectrum) that only he among all the PC's is capable of truly fulfilling. It has to be voluntary on Blognark's part in order for it to feel rewarding to the players at the table, and it should not be an act that some random mook or NPC could have fulfilled instead or people will wish it had not been Blognark.

It can be an act that occurs during combat but need not be.

For example, Blognark could die in combat against the antagonist you are trying to establish, perhaps by ensuring that Blognark is the only character of a level capable of combating the overpowered antagonist at this time. Blognark can choose to save his allies to buy them time to get stronger and avenge his death in the future.

Instead, maybe everybody could escape narrowly from the antagonist and Blognark could use his tremendous strength (let's just say I'm guessing that attribute based on the name) to prevent the collapse of an archway just long enough for all his allies to pass beneath it and escape. Blognark himself is unable to get out from under the arch safely and has a few knowing final words with his allies before he gives in to the impending muscle failure and is buried in the rubble.

Answer (score 7):

Don't do this. Killing player characters for story set-up is privileging the GM/DM over the players to an excessive degree. Role-playing is a *collaborative* game, and doing this sends the message to the players that one storyline is more important than all the work that a player has put into the longest-surviving character.

Comment: Im quite sure i wouldnt have to actually kill him. He would sacrifice himself for the group if the chance was given

Answer (score 4):

I wouldn't kill a long running character without first sounding out the player to see how he feels about it.

I've had characters that I played for months, even a year or more, that I wouldn't worry about if the GM promised something awesome, story-wise -- and characters where if the GM had killed them just for story (not because I made a biggish mistake), I'd likely have quit that gaming group.  Blognark sounds likely to be in the latter category, but without asking the player, there's no way to be sure.